# SAP B1 Addon Installation Failed

Tags: sapb1

I created a lightaddon. When I tried register the ard file of addon, I got error, add-on installation failed because another version is already installed. I followed the steps that are shown in below:

I checked SARI table in SBO Common but it wasn't record for the add-on,
I checked files AddOnsInstall.sbo and AddOnsLocalRegistration.sbo in C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP Business One but again there is nothing about the add-on,
Finally I deleted directory of add-on from C:\Program Files\SAP\SAP Business One\AddOns,

But still I cannot solve the problem, could you give me a solution?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You must check the table OARI. If it has rows, then DELETE OARI.

Comment: There isn't a table OARI in SBO-COMMON database, am I checking wrong database?

Comment: Sorry, I found the table now, should I delete all rows in database? There is another Add-on in SAP Business One, I don't want to delete it by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the AddOns folder in SAP Business One has read/write full rights?

Also did you package your addon as an x86 compatible?